# dsync replication requires user listing - which fails

Tags: dovecot

dovecot user '*"    - fails

dovecot user alan   - fails

dovecot user alan@mydomain.org    - works

Documentation says first command above is needed.

In 01-mail-stack-delivery.conf under /etc/dovecot/conf.d I have.....

```
passdb {
    driver = passwd-file
    args = username_format=%u scheme=ssha512 /etc/dovecot/passwd.db
    deny = no
    master = no
    pass = no
    skip = never
    result_failure = continue
    result_internalfail = continue
    result_success = return-ok
}

userdb {
    driver = static
    args = uid=5000 gid=5000 home=/var/mail/vmail/%d/%n
}
```

System user vmail has GID and UID of 5000

In the password file I list the virtual users that exist under vmail plus their SSH512 passwords.

So what works.....

```
doveadm user dimitriv@mydomain.org

field   value 

uid 5000

gid 5000

home    /var/mail/vmail/mydomain.org/dimitriv

mail    maildir:/var/mail/vmail/mydomain.org/dimitriv/mail:LAYOUT=fs

root@server123:/etc/dovecot/conf.d#
```

Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you already know

http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Replication

you should also read about iterate_query in your sql config.
It's the third query you need. Especially with doveadm user'*'